# Can I use overflow:hidden without an explicit height somehow?

Tags: css

I have an image with `float:left`, and I’d like it to overflow its parent, but cut off the overflow. Here’s what it looks like without any `overflow` rules:

[image]

Here’s what I want:

[image]

Here’s a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA5Lm/

[For some reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/), it was decided that `overflow:hidden` without an explicit height results in the element growing.

Can I somehow achieve the effect I’m after without setting an explicit height? An explicit height doesn’t work because I want this div to size automatically based on content length and browser width.

Comment: Do the images have a fixed width?

Comment: `overflow: hidden` (or any other value than `visible`) causes a box to create a block formatting context in which to contain floats. The expansion of the box to fit its floats is just one of the side effects when the box has `height: auto` (no explicit height). I can't find any explanation for *why* exactly a `overflow` that isn't `visible` creates a BFC, but it does.

Comment: What is that supposed to do when you resize the viewport [like here](http://jsfiddle.net/YvEcK/)?

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I think it makes sense for it to do exactly what’s shown in your fiddle. The real website layout is such that the image is only 100px wide, whereas the parent of this container is min-width 500px or so, thus never running into that situation.

Comment: @BoltClock It would indeed be interesting to know why that is the case. I can’t see anything [in the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) to this effect; isn’t this behaviour a violation of the spec then?

Comment: @romkyns: BFCs are discussed in [this part of the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). Since `height: auto` tells an element to be sized vertically depending on its contents, it'll expand to contain the entire floated image since it's now part of the same BFC. Therefore this is expected behavior.

Comment: This effect of stretching the height of the container is documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height). I'm finalizing an answer to your follow-up question right now. Sorry I took so long to get back to you!

Comment: @BoltClock no problem, the follow-up question wasn't a pressing issue anyway - more of a horizon broadening exercise. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion using overflow: hidden without setting dimensions doesn't make sense. If you don't want to specify the height of the container and **if your images have a fixed width** you could use this solution: http://jsfiddle.net/ZA5Lm/11/

The **image is positioned with absolute**, taking it out of the text-flow. However - and I'm aware that this may be ugly - you need to specify a padding-left to move the text away from the image.

Comment: Thanks, I think your solution will be acceptable, will try and see. I am curious, however, as to why you think overflow:hidden makes no sense without an _explicit_ size. Note that the parent element has a definite size _regardless_ of whether any sizes are set explicitly.

Comment: With parent element do you mean the **div**? Its height depends on its contents (if no height is specified). The div cannot grow with the text and ignore the image height. overflow can only hide when it has a boundary, that's why I say it makes no sense.

Comment: I do mean the div. Without overflow:hidden it _does_ grow with the text and ignore the image height. In this situation, the div has known borders, the image has known borders, so the only thing left is to intersect them and crop the image accordingly. Isn’t this perfectly well-defined?

Comment: Right of course, your screenshot shows this perfectly. But that's also thanks to float: left. Remove float: left and you'll get what I'm talking about.

Comment: I see what you mean now. It would still have worked, of course; the image would cause the div to grow to prevent overflow, unless constrained by something like max-height.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bit tricky (I use relative + absolute positioning and a specific padding to position text) but it does the effect you asked without changing markup or setting `height`:

```
body {
    padding: 10px;
}
img {
    float: left;
    position: absolute;
    left : 10px;
}
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px 10px 10px 280px;
    position : relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I just inserted style (even if `float:left` would be no longer necessary)

Answer (score 0):

I seen a post over at CSS-Tricks and it talked about this. Go check it out at - 
http://css-tricks.com/minimum-paragraph-widths/

It might be useful :) Good luck

Also just looked at your code and I added float: right to your div so it looks like this -

```
div {
border: 1px solid black;
padding: 10px;
float: right
/*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

Not sure if that's what you want?

Comment: Just tried that - it doesn’t seem to make the result look the way I showed in my question, which means it isn’t what I want :)