# Why does CSS2.1 define overflow values other than "visible" to establish a new block formatting context?

Tags: overflow, css

The CSS2.1 spec [mandates that `overflow` other than `visible` establish a new "block formatting context"](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). This strikes me as odd, that a property whose obvious purpose is to hide overflow without affecting layout, actually does affect layout in a major way.

It seems like overflow values other than `visible` combine two completely unrelated features: whether a BFC is created and whether the overflow is hidden. It’s not like "overflow:hidden" is completely meaningless without a BFC, because floats historically can overflow their parent element, [hiding the overflow without changing the layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942026) seems sensible.

What are the reasons behind this decision, assuming they are known? Have the people who worked on the spec described why this was decided to be the case?

Comment: This is unusual; other questions that similarly invite speculative answers and/or are only answerable by the few people involved in the decision, normally get closed. This site is really inconsistent with question closing.

Comment: @Timwi: Ideally, questions like this that *do* have definitive answers *shouldn't* get closed, but it's really up to the community to decide. See [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96310/is-miscategorization-of-obscure-questions-as-not-real-a-problem). I was actually quite hesitant to post this on SO myself for the reason mentioned, as well as the whole speculation thing, and instead take this to the mailing list. But I figured what the heck, let's see how this goes. If there are too many speculative answers, we can let the community handle it, or I can respond to flags.

Comment: @BoltClock I had my reservations too, so I tried to phrase it carefully to discourage speculation. An authoritative answer would be best, of course. Excellent example on Meta, by the way.

Comment: I've posted your question to the mailing list: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0023.html

Comment: Looks like we've completely forgotten about this question. Oops. Do you want me to post an answer quoting the replies in the mailing list thread?

Comment: @BoltClock I considered posting them myself, but since you went to the trouble of asking this on the mailing list, I thought it would be fair for you to get the credit too.

Comment: @BoltClock You took your time :P

Comment: @Paul Sweatte: I've always wondered if we needed a [css2] tag and a [css2.1] tag. On one hand, it would be nice to differentiate between the two once in a while; on the other hand, how often does one need to do so? I brought this up in a meta post, which may interest you: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142591/should-css2-and-css2-1-be-synonyms

Comment: @BoltClock Good post. As far as existing SO questions, it's important because CSS2 implies general cross-browser support and implementation, whereas CSS2.1 is usually related to validation and IDE integration issues.

Comment: @Paul Sweatte: The W3C asks that browsers implement CSS2.1, not CSS2, and indeed that's what they're doing here. Or were you referring to the use of "CSS2" to refer to CSS level 2 in general?

Comment: @Yi Jiang: I sure did :)

Comment: @BoltClock I was referring to general usage, not the W3C intent.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

I asked about this on the mailing list on your behalf; the thread can be found [here](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0023.html). In summary, [this has to do with scrolling content for the most part](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0024.html):

> Fundamentally, because if the spec didn't say this, then having floats intersect with something that's scrollable would require the browser to rewrap (around intruding floats) the contents of the scrollable element every time it scrolls.  This is technically what
>   CSS 2.0 required, but it was never implemented, and it would have been a huge problem for speed of scrolling.
>
> -David

Most likely, it refers to scrollable content in a box that may occur outside of the float's parent but would intersect with the float. I don't think this is related to rewrapping content around a float within a scrollable container, as that already happens naturally, plus [the float would clip into the container and scroll along with the rest of its content anyway](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow).

Finally this makes sense to me. In fact, I'm going to provide an example here so hopefully it makes sense to you and anyone else who may be wondering. Consider a scenario involving two boxes with the same fixed height and `overflow: visible` (the default), of which the first contains a float that stretches beyond its parent's height:

```html
<div>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
```

```css
/* Presentational properties omitted */
div {
    height: 80px;
}

div:first-child:before {
    float: left;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    content: 'Float';
}
```

[image]

Notice the similarity to one of the examples given in [section 9.5](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats). The second box here is simply shown to have overflowing content for the purposes of this answer.

This is fine since the content will never be scrolled, but when `overflow` is set to something other than `visible`, that causes the content to not only be clipped by the bounds of the box, but also to become scrollable. If the second box has `overflow: auto`, this is what it would look like had a browser implemented the original CSS2 spec:

[image]

Because of the float, attempting to scroll the content would cause the browser to have to rewrap it so it doesn't become obscured by the float (and what should happen to the part that scrolls out of the top edge?). It would probably look something like this when scrolled to the bottom:

[image]

The catch here is that the browser has to rewrap the content *every time it repaints it during scrolling*. For browsers that are capable of pixel-based smooth scrolling — which is to say, all of them — I can see why it would be a performance disaster! (And a user experience one, too.)

But that's for when the user can scroll the content, right? This would make sense for `overflow: auto` and `overflow: scroll`, but what about `overflow: hidden`?

Well, a common misconception is that a container with `overflow: hidden` simply hides content by clipping and cannot be scrolled. [This is not completely true](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2012Apr/0026.html):

> While scrolling UI is not provided, the content is still scrollable programmatically, and a number of pages perform just such scrolling (e.g. by setting `scrollTop` on the relevant element).
>
> -Boris

Indeed, this is what it'd look like if the second box was set to `overflow: hidden` and then scrolled to the bottom with the following JavaScript:

```js
var div = document.getElementsByTagName('div')[1];
div.scrollTop = div.scrollHeight;
```

[image]

Again, notice that the content would have to be rewrapped to avoid being obscured by the float.

Even though this wouldn't be as painful for performance as had scrolling UI been available, my best guess is that they made boxes with *any* `overflow` value other than `visible` generate a new BFC mainly for the sake of consistency.

---

And so, this change was brought about in CSS2.1, documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q55). Now if you apply an `overflow` value other than `visible` only to the second box, what a browser does is push *the entire box* aside to make way for the float, because the box now creates a new block formatting context that encloses its contents, instead of flowing around the float. This particular behavior is specified in the following [paragraph](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#bfc-next-to-float):

> The border box of a table, a block-level replaced element, or an element in the normal flow that establishes a new block formatting context (such as an element with 'overflow' other than 'visible') must not overlap the margin box of any floats in the same block formatting context as the element itself. If necessary, implementations should clear the said element by placing it below any preceding floats, but may place it adjacent to such floats if there is sufficient space. They may even make the border box of said element narrower than defined by [section 10.3.3.](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#blockwidth) CSS2 does not define when a UA may put said element next to the float or by how much said element may become narrower.

Here's what it looks like with `overflow: auto` for example:

[image]

Note that there is no clearance; if the second box had `clear: left` or `clear: both` it would be pushed *down*, not to the side, regardless of whether it established its own BFC.

If you apply `overflow: auto` to the first box instead, the float is clipped into its containing box with the rest of the content due to its fixed height, which is set to `80px` in the example code given above:

[image]

If you revert the first box to `height: auto` (the default value), either by overriding or removing the `height: 80px` declaration from above, it then *stretches* to the height of the float:

[image]

This happens to be [new in CSS2.1 as well](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#root-height), in that an element with `height: auto` that generates a new block formatting context (i.e. a *block formatting context root*) will stretch vertically to the height of its floats, and not just enough to contain its in-flow content unlike a regular box. The changes are documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q77) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q80). The change leading to the side-effect of shrinking the box so that it does not intersect the float is documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q58).

In both of these cases, no matter what you do to the second box, it will never be affected by the float because it has been restricted by the bounds of its container.

Comment: Isn't `overflow:visible` scrollable too?

Comment: @HRJ: No, it's not.

Answer (score 4):

I know this will be a speculative answer, however after reading the specifications a few times here is my view on this:

What section 9.4.1 is talking about is any block element that does not fully contain or does not fill the containment space.  For example when you float an element it is no longer filling 100% of the parent, like in-flow elements do.  Inline blocks, table cells, and table captions are also elements that you can affect height and width but that are not intrinsically 100% of the parent (yes table>tr>td is one that would fill 100% of it's parent but it is designed to allow for multiple td's so the td doesn't count as it will automatically shrink to accommodate additional td's) this also applies to any overflow other than visible because it breaks the containment of the block element.

So if I am reading this correctly the way it works is the 9.4.1 section is referring to block elements that break the default containment rules of the block elements as specified by section 9.2.1

Comment: Your summary turns out to be partially right. Although, rather than breaking rules, they just set different rules for them. See the last part of my answer for an explanation.