# overflow:hidden can't prevent collapsing margins

Tags: css, overflow

overflow:hidden can establish a new blocking format context,and blocking format context can prevent collapsing margins.
but in this example,it doesn't work,the gap between them is still 20px.
why?
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#collapsing-margins

.mod-a,.mod-b{margin:20px;overflow:hidden}

[image]

Comment: Can we see some code? Currently we do have to do some guessing as to what you mean, while code would really help clarify things.

Answer (score 2):

**overflow:hidden** do not collapse with their [in-flow](http://jsfiddle.net/fXz57/1/) children but it's collapsed with other DIV's  . Write like this:

```
div{
    margin:20px 0;
    background:red;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    float:left;
    clear:left;
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/fXz57/

Comment: So `float: left;` triggers block formatting context, and `clear: left;` disables float or what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Overflow has nothing to do with margins or paddings. If you don't want a margin, set `margin` to 0 instead of trying to change `overflow`.

Comment: no,you haven't konw what do it mean,overflow:hidden can establish a new blocking format context,and blocking format context will prevent collapsing margins.

Comment: You mean there's a bug in all browsers? Wow.

Comment: Hopefully you've figured out by now that it's not a bug in any browser ;) It's more of a side effect of a workaround for [something else](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515).

Answer (score 0):

There is margin because in your class you have given margin as 20 px. Remove the margin from css class .mod-a,.mod-b:20px.

Overflow-hidden has nothing to do with this. It is used when you have a long element inside other say label is 50 px width and text inside is 200 px. Then overflow:hidden will hide the oth