# CSS overflow property

Tags: css, overflow

I've found some CSS templates where some classes have the overflow:hidden property, but no size defined. If I recall correctly, block elements stretch to fit their content unless otherwise specified. Since this is not the case, I feel that putting the overflow:hidden is pointless and I can delete it without hesitation. Is this right or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While that's the main purpose of the `overflow` property, it's not the only effect it has on rendering. The other major effect it has is that setting `overflow` to anything other than `visible` (the default) causes a block box to establish its own [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting).

This is mainly used to contain floats without the need for a clearfix; however that isn't the only effect of having a new BFC; there are a number of other corner cases that are better described elsewhere in the spec. Also see [this lengthy write-up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515) on the reasoning for this behavior (which, oddly enough, has very little to do with containing floats; that actually ends up being nothing more than a side effect).

So if you remove that `overflow` declaration, you may break float layouts, among other things. I suggest avoiding doing so unless it's absolutely necessary or you're sure it won't affect the layout.

Comment: Good answer. In my case there's no child floating element, so I guess it would be safe to remove the declaration. However, I'll let it be just in case I forget why it was there in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

If there are floating children inside that div, then `overflow: hidden` is probably there to contain them.

`overflow: hidden` creates a new block formatting context, and elements that create new block formatting contexts contain floats.

Answer (score 0):

It may depend. if your div contains some floated elements you could use

```
div {
   height: auto;
   overflow : hidden;
}
```

as a workaround for the clearing. So I wouldn't delete that rule without seeing the effect on the layout

Answer (score 0):

`overflow:hidden` can come in handy if you have a child element with a width specified which is greater than the container's max allowed width. Otherwise it will stretch the container.

[See example](http://jsfiddle.net/yJRuL/)

A common use of this is when displaying a [carousel](http://www.pixelzdesign.com/blog_view.php?id=55), with floated child elements. The elements need to appear inline, but hidden, so that they can come into vision when the `left` CSS property is changed.

Comment: This was mentioned in the question. The issue is that the stylesheet *doesn't* have a specified width (or height).

Comment: @BoltClock Perhaps you have misread my answer. I'm referring to a child element, not the actual elements width

Comment: Oops, yeah, that is different.

Comment: @BoltClock I've updated my answer to make this is a bit clearer