# Effect of overflow:auto on floated divs

Tags: css, html

Short version:  Why does `overflow:auto` cause a `div` to the right of a left floated `div` not to wrap its text around the left floated `div`?  (Bonus:  Is this an acceptable way to accomplish a column effect?)

Long version...

I have two `div`s that I wish to be next to each other, and displayed as columns.  The `div` on the left has a specific width and height.  And the `div` on the left is shorter than the `div` on the right. However, I do not want the text in the right `div` to wrap under the left div.

Here was my first attempt...

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid grey;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;">
        Div on the left.
    </div>
    <div>
        Imagine lots and lots of text here...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

...I knew the text in the right `div` would wrap under the left `div`.  And it did.

Then I remembered a page I had created that had a column effect.  I had copied and pasted it from I know not where.  All it did was assign `overflow:auto` to the `div` on the right.  It looks like this...

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid grey;
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        float:left;">
        Div on the left.
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto">
        Imagine lots and lots of text here...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

Voila, the right `div`s text no longer wrapped under the first (left) `div`!  The second (right) `div` appeared as a column.

So, I read everything I could find on `overflow:auto` and found no mention of why I should see this behaviour.  Can anyone explain it to me?

Also, is this an acceptable way to achieve a column effect?

Comment: r u expecting second div to wrap the text to second line of the second div?

Comment: Yes, I see now that my use of the word wrap is misleading.  By "wrap" I meant wrapping UNDER the first div.  I will try to find a better phrasing and edit the post.

Comment: I like how nobody actually tried to answer the question at hand.

Comment: @BoltClock:  Yes I noticed that.  But they WERE trying to be helpful nonetheless.  Thanks for actually answering the question.

Comment: Yes, that's true. I'll give them that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`overflow: auto` (or anything but `visible`) causes your second `div` to create a new [block formatting context](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#block-formatting). This means the text within that `div` is now in its own formatting context, rather than sharing the same one as your first, left-floating `div` (which is the containing block of *both* `div`s), and so it is no longer allowed to flow around the first `div`.

Floats also generate their own BFCs, but that doesn't exactly relate to the matter at hand. It does however also prevent reflow, achieving a column effect, as shown in the other answers.

Is this an acceptable way of creating a column effect? I don't know, but it does seem unconventional. You can just float the second `div` as well instead for the reason mentioned above (although even that, in favor of upcoming true layout modes like flexbox and grids, is now seen as a browser compatibility hack these days, but is the best we've got for the time being).

Remember that inline content is designed to be able to flow naturally around floated content; see [CSS2.1, §9.5 Floats](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#floats).

Remember also that the *purpose* of `overflow` is to control content overflow in a box with a limited size. That it causes a box to create a new BFC, influencing floats as a result, is but a side effect, the reason for which is explored [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943503/why-does-css2-1-define-overflow-values-other-than-visible-to-establish-a-new-b/11854515#11854515). It's a lengthy read, but it includes a bit about preventing reflow, which I'll quote here for ease of reference:

> And so, this change was brought about in CSS2.1, documented [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/changes.html#q55). Now if you apply an `overflow` value other than `visible` only to the second box, what a browser does is push *the entire box* aside to make way for the float, because the box now creates a new block formatting context that encloses its contents, instead of flowing around the float. Here's what it looks like with `overflow: auto` for example:
>
> [image]
>
> Note that there is no clearance; if the second box had `clear: left` or `clear: both` it would be pushed *down*, not to the side, regardless of whether it established its own BFC.

By the way, yes, this means your clearing `div` needs to be there if you want to always clear the first `div`.

Answer (score 1):

To get the divs next to each other they both will need a float and fit in the surrounding div.

**Example:**

```
<div style="width:200px;">
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
      content
  </div>
  <div style="width:100px; float:left;">
      content
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the outlining div to grow with the largest div place `overflow:hidden;` to the div.. If that div doesnt have a height with it then it will scale with the larges div.

**Preview:**
http://jsfiddle.net/WzVBE/

Comment: I forgot to mention that before trying `overflow:auto` I tried left floating the second `div`.  There was an undesired effect with that.  When I made the browser too narrow, the right `div` moved down under the left `div`.  But I want the `div` on the right to stay to the right of the left `div` regardless of the width of the browser.

Comment: It is depending on the width of the parent div. If the parent has a width of 200 px then both childeren may not get higher then 200px. In other words : 100 + 100 = 200. is correct.... 150+100 = 250 = overflow, and then the right div will fall below the left one. If you want to stay next to each other then use 50% on both.

Comment: Oh!  Now I see what you mean.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Remove `float:left` from the first div.

```
<div>
    <div style="border:1px solid grey; width:100px; height:100px;">
        Div on the left.
    </div>
    <div style="overflow:auto;  ">
        Imagine lots and lots of text here...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"/>
</div>​
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aErTV/2/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can try this

```
<div style="width:800px; background-color:#CCC">
    <div style="width:300px; height:100px; float:left; background-color:#CCC">
        Div on the left.
    </div>
    <div style="height:100px; float:left; width:500px; background-color:#999">
        Imagine lots and lots of text here...
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"/>
</div>
```

Comment: As I commented in another response, left floating both `div`s causes the second `div` to appear under the first `div` if the browser is too narrow to show them next to each other.  But I want the second `div` to always be on the right regardless of browser width.