# CSS Calc alternative

Tags: css, css-calc

I am trying to dynamicly change the width of a div using CSS and no jquery. **The following code will work** in the following browsers: http://caniuse.com/calc

```
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 500px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 500px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(100% - 500px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(100% - 500px);
```

**I want also support IE 5.5 and higher**, i found the following: expression. Is this the correct usage:

```
/* IE-OLD */
width: expression(100% - 500px);
```

**Can I also support Opera and the Android browser?**

Comment: Wow, IE 5.5? Are you distributing this to the Ark or something?

Comment: How did you knew that! Well i am trying at least to get it working on 6 or 7.

Comment: IE6-7 are close to dead, and IE8 doesn't support `expression` - ["Dynamic properties (also called "CSS expressions") are no longer supported in Internet Explorer 8 and later, in IE8 Standards mode and higher. "](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: You won't be able to support the browsers you're talking about with using some JavaScript I'm afraid.

Comment: Are you sure you're not having an [XY-problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? *Why* are you trying to do this? Perhaps something simple like margins/paddings and/or a wrapper element may solve your layout issue?

Comment: Thanks for the information. Time to upgrade everyone to IE 10 ;)

Comment: If I were you, I'd rethink my support for IE5.5. IE6 is officially pronounced dead by Microsoft. I suspect (hope) IE7 to follow soon too. Not to get the old discussion back, but do you really want this? If the answer is yes, then by all means go for it.

Comment: I'm not so sure if this really is a direct alternative to calc(). There's still an advantage to using calc() for dynamic height. Say sidebar is gonna get longer than content then that would not expand the page in length.

Comment: Since padding is scrollable, you may want to use transparent `border` instead. Just replace `padding-left: 300px;` with `border-left: 300px solid transparent`.

Answer (score 120, accepted):

Almost always `box-sizing: border-box` can replace a calc rule such as `calc(100% - 500px)` used for layout.

For example:

If I have the following markup:

```
<div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

Instead of doing this: (Assuming that the sidebar is 300px wide)

```
.content {
  width: calc(100% - 300px);
}
```

Do this:

```
.sideBar {
     position: absolute; 
     top:0;
     left:0;
     width: 300px;
}
.content {
    padding-left: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body,
div {
  height: 100%;
}
.sideBar {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 300px;
  background: orange;
}
.content {
  padding-left: 300px;
  width: 100%;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div class="sideBar">sideBar</div>
<div class="content">content</div>
```

**PS:** I won't work in IE 5.5 (hahahaha) , but it will work in IE8+ , all mobile, and all modern browsers ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css3-boxsizing))

**[Width Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/T92Fk/233/)**

**[Height Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/T92Fk/315/)**

I just found [this post](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/) from Paul Irish's blog where he also shows off box-sizing as a possible alternative for simple calc() expressions: (bold is mine)

> One of my favorite use-cases that border-box solves well is columns. I
>   might want to divide up my grid with 50% or 20% columns, but want to
>   add padding via px or em. **Without CSS’s upcoming calc() this is
>   impossible… unless you use border-box**.

**NB:** The above technique does indeed look the same as would a corresponding calc() statement. There is a difference though. When using a calc() rule the value of the width of the content div will actually be `100% - width of fixed div`, however with the above technique, the actual width of the content div is the full 100% width, yet it has *the appearance* of 'filling up' the remaining width. (which is probably good enough for want most people need here)

That said, if it *is important* that the content div's width is actually `100% - fixed div width`  then a different technique - which makes use of block formatting contexts - may be used (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1767270/703717) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11854515/703717) for the gory details):

1) float the fixed width div

2) set `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto` on the content div

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/T92Fk/316/)

Comment: Why are these 2 needed?  `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` & `box-sizing: border-box;`. Can't I just specify padding & width

Comment: @buffer - No, because the default box-model uses `box-sizing-content-box` which means that if you add padding - the width of your element increases. With `box-sizing:border-box` the padding is an inner padding and the width of the element remains according to what you set it to be.

Comment: What to do if it's the height that's a combination of px and % and  the % should take up the remaining height?

Comment: How would this change if it was with height instead of width?

Comment: @streetlight - I added a demo for height as well in the post

Comment: Knew it, but didn't think of it. Old android is still common, supports box sizing but not calc. a simple absolute and padding saves the day.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it using a border becuase the way I tried, the border was still before the padding which doesn't help. 
If you can use inner padding, is there a way to do an inner border?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/T92Fk/376/  A part of a scrollbar is hidden under the Header block

Comment: @IvanRave Use position relative instead of absolute in that case: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/8fv1a2ob/ (I also made a few other modifications :) )

Comment: In this case it can be done without `border-box` simply by omitting `width: 100%`:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/45626311/822138

Answer (score 36):

Just have a fallback before the calc will do the trick.

```
width: 98%;               /* fallback for browsers without support for calc() */
width: calc(100% - 1em);
```

See more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc

Answer (score 18):

**use this**

```
    .content
{
    width: 100%;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-right: 500px;
    margin-right: -500px;
}
```

Comment: Isn't this the same thing Danield proposed in his answer?

Comment: No, it isn't.. If you have an image of 500px and if you want to display a flanked text of (100%-500px), the only way I've found to show them correctly in IE8 is to add a negative margin to text. Otherwise text is displayed as a block.

Comment: margin-right: -500px got mine working for text. Don't know if it overrode something I missed, I don't care. Life saver.

Answer (score 0):

Just spent the best part of 3 hours trying to workaround this for a specific case on andriod devices, couldnt get box sizing to work so i've linked it into my JS as a dirty workaround... no jQuery required though! :)

Taken on working code on andriod 2.3.

```
<div class="sessionDiv" style="width:auto;">
<img> <!-- image to resize -->
</div>
<div class="sessionDiv" style="width:auto;">
<img> <!-- image to resize -->
</div>
```

JS with event listeners

```
var orient =
{
    orientation:window.orientation,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    check: function()
    {
        // if orientation does not match stored value, update
        if(window.orientation !== this.orientation)  
        {
            this.orientation = window.orientation; //set new orientation
            this.width = window.innerWidth; //set new width
            this.adjustIrritatingCSS(this.width); //change ui to current value
        }
        //if width does not match stored value, update
        if(window.innerWidth !== this.width)
        {
            this.width = window.innerWidth; //set new width
            this.adjustIrritatingCSS(this.width); //change ui to current value
        }
    },
    adjustIrritatingCSS: function(screenWidth)
    {   
    //disgusting workaround function
        var titleBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('sessionDiv'); 
        var i = titleBoxes.length;
        var sessWidth = screenWidth - 300; // calc(100% - 300px); -> equivalent
        while(i--)
        {
            titleBoxes[i].style.width = String( sessWidth + "px"); 
            //resize image in auto sized div
        }
        sessWidth = null; //clear width
        titleBoxes = null; //clear nodelist
        i = null; // clear index int
    }
};

window.onload = function()
{
    window.addEventListener('resize', function(){orient.check();}); 
    //on resize, check our values for updates and if theres changes run functions
    window.addEventListener('orientationchange', function(){orient.check();});
    //on rotate, check our values for updates and if theres changes run functions
    setInterval(function(){orient.check();}, 2000);
    //occasionally check our values for updates and if theres changes run functions(just incase!!)
    orient.adjustIrritatingCSS(orient.width); 
    //sets value on first run
};
```

Hope this helps anyone who cant get the box-sizing working!
PS I have experienced problems with ios using this...

Comment: It looks like you need the -webkit- prefix on Android 2.3: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing

Answer (score 0):

Change #menuLog width with % or px and you will see magic. Works with every device even < 2.3

```css
*{
 -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#menuLog{
  width:30%;
  /*width:300px;*/
 height: 60px;
 padding: 5px;
 background-color: #ddd;
}
#menuLog > div[inline-log="1"]{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin-right: -60px;
}
#menuLog > div[inline-log="1"] > div[inline-log="1.1"]{
 margin-right: 60px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: red;
}
#menuLog > div[inline-log="2"]{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 60px;
 height: 100%;
}
#menuLog > div[inline-log="2"] > div[inline-log="2.1"]{
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 width: 55px;
 height: 100%;
 background-color: yellow;
 margin-left:5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuLog">
  <div inline-log="1">
    <div inline-log="1.1">
      One
    </div>
  </div><div inline-log="2">
     <div inline-log="2.1">
      Two
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add the no-calc, no-border-box (i.e., CSS2) alternative.

Normal-flow block elements initially have `width: auto`, which is effectively the width of the containing block minus the margin, border, and padding widths.

The [example above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18570513/822138) can be done, without border-box, simply as

```
.content {
    padding-left: 300px;
}
```

Similarly, with

```
.content {
  margin-left: 1px;
  border-left: 1em solid;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

the effective width is `100% - 1px - 1em - 1rem`.

For absolutely positioned elements, `height: auto` has similar properties:

```
.content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  border-bottom: 1em solid;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

Here the effective height is `100% - 1px - 1em - 1rem`.