# MVC4 bundling: Minification failed because of css3-feature?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, css, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I want to use MVC4 bundling and minification, but I always get this error message as comment in my not minified css file:

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
(534,29): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(534,29): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(534,29): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(534,29): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
(535,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(535,26): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(535,26): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(535,26): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
(536,25): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(536,25): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(536,25): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(536,25): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
(537,24): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(537,24): run-time error CSS1019: Unexpected token, found ' '
(537,24): run-time error CSS1042: Expected function, found ' '
(537,24): run-time error CSS1062: Expected semicolon or closing curly-brace, found ' '
 */
```

The corresponding lines in CSS are:

```
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 0.5em);
width: -moz-calc(100% - 0.5em);
width: -ms-calc(100% - 0.5em);
width: -o-calc(100% - 0.5em);
```

What can I do for minification to work with css3's calc feature?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you'll be able to use it in the current implementation. I think you have two things working against you here.

1. Per http://www.w3.org/standards/techs/css#w3c_all nearly everything is still a working draft. It probably isn't worth the effort to implement something in `System.Web.Optimization` if it's going to change, and cause more issues in the long term.
2. `calc()` is currently apart of [CSS Values and Units Module Level 3](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/) which states:

   > The following features are at-risk and may be dropped during the CR period: ‘calc()’, ‘toggle()’, ‘attr()’."

So with those things, Microsoft may not be on the bleeding edge of CSS3. Granted, this is more than likely a bug since that syntax isn't completely off the wall. Hopefully they open source `System.Web.Optimization` soon so people could fix issues like this. But they've been promising to open source it for nearly a year now.

In the meantime, you could try to prebundle the file locally on your machine where you have a lot of control over it. Or maybe try a different bundling/minification system like [Cassette](http://getcassette.net/).

Comment: Yeah... thanks. Obviously MS implemented more intelligence that I'd thought is needed for minification. I tried Cassette but had some other problems I can't remember right now...

Comment: @Ollie Another idea would be to implement your own `IBundleTransform` and use a minifier that does work for what you want to do. Maybe more work than you're willing to do though.

Comment: caniuse.com shows that actually all modern browsers support calc() and it really works fine. I decided to use a workaround described here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18570513/1155881 Thanks Microsoft! ;-( Now minification works ok.

Answer (score 1):

I answer my own question to tell you that I use **Bundle Transformer** now in connection with **YUI Compressor**. This works really fine and the syntax is very similar to the Microsoft way.
Have a look at it!