# MVC Bundling breaking my calc CSS statements by removing spaces?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, bundling-and-minification

I have css statements like this:

```
margin-left: calc(50% - 480px);
```

Which work fine unminified but as soon as I begin minifying, the statement gets changed to:

```
margin-left: calc(50%- 480px);
```

Rendering all calc statements broken.  Similar things happen with width, max-width, min-width, etc.  Is there any way I can change the behavior of the bundle to leave those CSS properties alone?

Currently I'm just using `bundles.Add(new Bundle())` to prevent minification entirely, but it would be nice if I could minify correctly.

Comment: Have you set `<compilation debug="false" />` in `Web.config` or `BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;` in `BundleConfig.cs`?

Comment: @JohnH - yes to the first, no to the second

Comment: @RobVious `calc` works fine minified in mine. Try updating to the latest Web Grease

Comment: Since it's a css feature that's new and not implemented by all browsers why not put only this kind of css in separate file, name it like *.calc.css and add this exception to BundleCollection.IgnoreList property in BundleConfig.cs

Comment: The calc feature is still in a Candidate Recomendation period. Therefore Microsoft did not include it in it's bundling.

You can see this related post for more informations and recommendations : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19361403/mvc4-bundling-minification-failed-because-of-css3-feature

Comment: This appears fixed in newer versions of MVC. Updated 4 to 5.2.7 and it is no longer happening.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

This is an issue of the optimizer.

To avoid the miniffier to remove the whitespaces, group the affected element with parenthesis. That workarrounds the issue.

```
margin-left: calc((50%) - 480px);
```

Comment: Simple but effective answer.

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the answer above:
if you use:

```
margin-left: calc((50%) + 480px);
```

You should rewrite it as:

```
margin-left: calc((50%) - -480px);
```

Since it didn't seem to fix (50%)+ for me.

Answer (score 3):

If the default css minification is not doing what you need, you can always use a third party one.

bundling allows you to use your own transformations using `IBundleTransform`

`var bundle = new Bundle("~/Content/css", myCustomCssTransform);`

there are many different bundlers - [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=IBundleTransform)

for example you could use YUI compressor:

```
    using System.IO;
using System.Web.Optimization;
using Yahoo.Yui.Compressor;

namespace Bundler.Utilities
{
 public enum contentType
 {
  javascript,
  css
 }

 public class YUITransform : IBundleTransform
 {

  readonly string _contentType = string.Empty;

  public YUITransform(contentType contentType)
  {
   if (contentType == contentType.css)
   {
    this._contentType = "text/css";
   }
   else
   {
    this._contentType = "text/javascript";
   }
  }

  public void Process(BundleContext context, BundleResponse bundle)
  {
   bundle.ContentType = this._contentType;

   string content = string.Empty;


   foreach (FileInfo file in bundle.Files)
   {

    using (StreamReader fileReader = new
StreamReader(file.FullName)) {
     content += fileReader.ReadToEnd();
     fileReader.Close();
    }

   }

   bundle.Content = Compress(content);
  }

  string Compress(string content) {

   if (_contentType == "text/javascript")
   {
     return JavaScriptCompressor.Compress(content);
   }
   else
   {
    return CssCompressor.Compress(content,
                           CssCompressionType.StockYuiCompressor
);
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal as referring to [CSS Values and Units Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-css3-values-20130730/)  it states

> The following features are at-risk and may be dropped during the CR
>   period: ‘calc()’, ‘toggle()’, ‘attr()’."

If you could skip the spaces there, that wouldn't be a complete minifying. An option is replacing spaces with unicode caracter `\00A0`

Answer (score 1):

No idea why but calc((50%) - 480px) didnt work for me, however the following worked:

subtraction:

```
margin-left: calc(((100%) - (480px)))
```

addition:

```
margin-left: calc((100%) - -480px)
```

Answer (score 1):

Beware of using variables in calc. You can end up with another CssMinify() bug:

```
@myVariable: 0em;
margin-left: calc((50%) - @myVariable);
```

is compressed and unit is cut off:

```
margin-left: calc((50%) - 0);
```

**and it is not valid calc() call too!**

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issue has been fixed in the version 2.4.9 of YUI Compressor, which can be accessed from here https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.yahoo.platform.yui/yuicompressor?repo=bsi-business-systems-integration-ag-scout. I have used this css file:

```
body{
    font-size: calc(50% - 3px);
    font-size: calc(50% + 3px);
    font-size: calc(50% + +3px);
    font-size: calc((50%) + (3px));
    font-size: calc(50% + (+3px));
    font-size: calc(50% + (3px));
    font-size: calc(50% - (-3px));
    font-size: calc(50% - -3px);
}
```

and running this command:

```
java -jar yuicompressor-2.4.9-BSI-2.jar --line-break 0 -o process.css.min.gz file.css
```

generates this output, which looks good:

```
body{font-size:calc(50% - 3px);font-size:calc(50% + 3px);font-size:calc(50% + +3px);font-size:calc((50%)+(3px));font-size:calc(50% + (+3px));font-size:calc(50% + (3px));font-size:calc(50% - (-3px));font-size:calc(50% - -3px)}
```