# calc not working ie 11

Tags: css, cross-browser, css-calc

After researching I confirmed that calc should work for ie8+ but it is not working for me.

Here is a JS fiddle I made:

http://jsfiddle.net/75tzyLoo/

here is the code:
HTML:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#outer{
    width:400px;
    background-color:black;
    height:200px;
}
#inner{
    width:calc(80%-100px);
    width:expression(80%-100px);
    background-color:red;
    height:100%;

}
```

and here is the output I see: [image: JS Fiddle output for calc not working]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034397/css-calc-alternative says to use `width: expression(100% - 500px);`

Comment: `calc()` isn't IE8+ but IE9+. Refs: [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#search=calc) and [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/units-values/)

Comment: I also discovered that `z-index: calc(100 + 1);` and even `z-index: calc(101);` are broken in IE11.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

"-" should be surrounded with spaces `width:calc(80% - 100px);`

<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/75tzyLoo/2/)</kbd>

Comment: Lol. thanks . you'd think it would not go crazy over a missing space :). Cant accept your answer now but will once the timer runs out InshAllah.

Comment: wierd way to do math ^^

Comment: Whitespace is a killer on the calc() property. Also of note: calc() will not work properly with viewport units vw/vh and another type of unit. ie: calc(100vw - 25px) will not render, but calc(100vw - 2vw) would.

Answer (score 20):

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4dgaurav/75tzyLoo/1/)**

`width:calc(80%-100px);` change to `width:calc(80% - 100px);` (space between '-' sign)

Comment: Yeah I know! I was busy posting the answer and didn't realize that answer was already posted..:)

Comment: <1 min difference. Probably didn't notice. Will upvote at least, but JunM gets the green tick :).

Comment: yeah sure..:) @JunM deserves it!