# how do 100% -100px with css and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net

I'm using the same code in css and jquery:

```
width: 100% -100px;
```

so, I use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.left').css('width', '100%').css('width', '-=100px');
});
```

But it does not work properly when the browser is resized after loading the site will. I want working similar this code:

```
.left
{
    width: 80%; //100% -100px;
}
.right
{
    width: 20%; //100px;
}
```

Comment: If you need non-CSS (JQuery only) solution - run the same code on resize event (as you really setting width to fixed pixel size, not `calc` as shown in all answers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution using CSS2:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}
.right {
    width: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
}
.left, .right {
    height: 50px;
}

.container{
    position: relative;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8u196rjb/)**

In the above fiddle, I applied `position: absolute` to the `.left` container. This makes that container not to stretch the parent element (*hence, the layout will break*). If you are sure that `.left` container's height will be less than the `.right` container, then go with the above solution. or else if you know that `.left` container's height will be more than the `.right` container's height then go with this solution. [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/8u196rjb/2/).

If you are unsure of the heights of those containers and you don't want to break the layout, then I think it is better to go with javascript.  (*no need of javascript, if you know any of the container's height*)

Answer (score 4):

UPDATE: **[Demo using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/vq74kngp/1/)**

Option 1:

Using jQuery:

```
function resize_div(selector){
    var curr_width = selector.width(); // get the current width
    new_width = curr_width - 100;
    selector.css('width', new_width);
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.left').css('width', '100%'); // set the width to 100% initially
    resize_div($('.left')); // then resize width on document ready
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    $('.left').css('width', '100%'); // set the width to 100% initially
    resize_div($('.left')); // resize width everytime the window is resized
});
```

**[HERE'S A DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vq74kngp/1/)**

Option 2:

You can use css calc(), like:

```
/* Firefox */
width: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
/* WebKit */
width: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
/* Opera */
width: -o-calc(100% - 100px);
/* Standard */
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Option 3:

using [padding and box-sizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034397/css-calc-alternative)

```
.some-div
{
   padding-right: 50px;
   padding-left: 50px;
   width: 100%;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: I do not want use css3. please help me with css2. and this width size with jquery to be set.

Answer (score 2):

In CSS3, you can use [`calc`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc):

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Depending on browser support, your mileage may vary. The linked page contains a [browser compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: I do not want use css3. please help me with css2

Answer (score 1):

You can use calc();

```
 width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

Comment: I do not want use css3. please help me with css2

Answer (score 1):

All other people has posted very good solution using CSS3 but if you want to make it using only jQuery then here is the workaround -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.left').css('width', $('.left').parent().width() - 100);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r2eqeL2a/6/)**

Answer (score 1):

[***Demo***](http://jsbin.com/nuqenemudoje/2/edit)

`box-sizing` is CSS3 property. If you like it then you can use this code otherwise there is another `calc` property which I think isn't well supported.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="m">
    <h1>100%-100px
  </div>
  <div id="s">
    100px for me
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
html, body {
  height:100%;
}
#m {
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  height:100%;
  margin-left:-100px;
  padding-left:100px;
  vertical-align:top;

  box-sizing: border-box;
  float:left;
}
#s {
  float:left;
  vertical-align:top;
  height:100%;
  width:100px;

  background:green;
}
```