# Proportinally scale div together with image without using calc()

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, calc

I'm trying to proportinally scale a div together with the image next to it.
(so that the image is always 50% width, height is proportinally scaled, and the div needs to behave exactly the same in height and width)

My code example is probably easier to understand: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/myKZJE?editors=110

```
.actualcomments{
    max-height: calc(100% - 60px);
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Note that it's a bit more complex than just the above, I also needed to wrap the div three times.

Problem = IE is sometimes doing the calc(), but sometimes ignoring the calc, so the layout is all messed up.
Can I have the same effect (div scales together with image) without using the calc() method?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes it is possible! Calculate it yourself. You have a wrapper of some sort?

Comment: @bbvanee what do you mean with "You have a wrapper of some sort?"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16034397/css-calc-alternative

Comment: @bbvanee This doesn't work for me: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XJYLRw

Comment: are you willing to use jquery?

Comment: @bbvanee As last resort: yes.

Comment: `$('#yourDIV').css('height', '100%').css('height', '-=60px');`

Comment: Thanks for your answer @bbvanee, but I still can't seem to make it work, could you maybe try to fork it? (sorry)