# CSS Calc alternative for text input fields width

Tags: html, css

I need a CSS `calc` alternative for browsers (like the default Android browser) that don't support it to define dynamically the width of input text fields, leaving at right only a space for the submit button.

My actual CSS code:

```
div .feedburner form input[type=text] {
    width: calc(100% - 76px);
}
```

I tried this, adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18570513/1354580), but without success:

```
div .feedburner form input[type=text] {
    /** width: calc(100% - 76px); */
    padding-right: 76px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: What **specifically**...didn't work?

Comment: Also, which version of the browser? - http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

Comment: [Compatibility of css property Calc()](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) is above Android 4.0. Add your version for less confusions.

Comment: @Zeratops I don't know where to look for this :(.

Comment: I improved the question. @Paulie_D - I don't know where to look for the browser version :(.

Comment: Browser version is usually: Help > About <browserName>

Comment: No, in Android (though I've only got Android Chrome to test with): ⋮ > Settings > About Chrome; the version is listed under 'Application version.'

Answer (score 2):

In some situations you can use a trick with an invisible border and `border-box` sizing model

```css
.calc .content {
    background: red;
    height: 250px;
}
.noCalc .content {
    background: green;
    height: 250px;
}
.calc {  
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
}
.noCalc {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border-right: 100px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="calc">
  <div  class="content">CALC</div>
</div>
<div class="noCalc">
  <div  class="content">NO CALC</div>
</div>
```