# Why does an svg element not respect CSS 'bottom', 'top', 'left', 'right' properties?

Tags: html, css, svg, size

I sometimes find it convenient to give the size of an element in terms of the `bottom`, `top`, `left` and `right` properties, rather than using `width` and `height`. This is, for example, the accepted answer here:

[CSS 100% height with padding/margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/485827/css-100-height-with-padding-margin/485887)

However, for some reason this doesn't work with an `svg` element. I've tried the following example with the latest stable Firefox and Chrome. The `svg` element inexplicably wants to take a size of 300x150:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/1928/)

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

While it's not mentioned directly in the spec (at least in my knowledge)`<svg>` [is considered](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/2007Jan/0007.html) as a [*replaced element*](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element) (unlike `<div>` which is a non-replaced block level element).

For *absolutely positioned replaced elements*, if the values of `top`/`bottom` are over-constrained, once you set a value for `top`, `bottom` would be ignored. This is true for `left`/`right` properties as well.

> **[10.3 Calculating widths and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_widths_and_margins)** / **[10.3.8 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-width)**
>
> 6. If at this point the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for either 'left' (in case the 'direction' property of the containing
>      block is 'rtl') or 'right' (in case 'direction' is 'ltr') and solve
>      for that value.

> **[10.6 Calculating heights and margins](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#Computing_heights_and_margins)** / **[10.6.5 Absolutely positioned, replaced elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#abs-replaced-height)**
>
> 6. If at this point the values are over-constrained, ignore the value for
>      'bottom' and solve for that value.

Hence the absolutely positioned `<svg>` element would be position with the respect to `top` and `left` offsets.

Comment: Interesting. Yes, that must be it. Thanks! Though I have to say, I don't like how they handled this. **(1)** *"A replaced element often has intrinsic dimensions"*... so not always, and they should respect `right` and `bottom` for elements that don't. **(2)** Even if an element has intrinsic dimensions, isn't it my prerogative to override those? Making `top`/`bottom`/`left`/`right` inconsistent with `width`/`height` does not seem like an elegant move.

Comment: @mhelvens Well, I agree with your point of view but I'm not aware of the actual reason behind this treatment/convention. However for the second question, in fact you *can* [alter/override dimensions](http://jsfiddle.net/Rpdr9/1929/) of the replaced element (via `width`/`height` just like images). The issue is not about the `width`/`height` but it's about how `top`/`bottom` and `left`/`right` properties interact with each other.

Comment: With that second comment I just meant this: There are some basic equations that you'd simply expect to hold: `left + width = right` and `top + height = bottom` (sort of; you know what I mean). But they sort of drew this arbitrary line, where `width`/`height` can override intrinsic dimensions, but `top`/`left`/`right`/`bottom` can't, breaking those basic equations. Furthermore, doing so forces the spec to make the rather arbitrary decision that `top` is more important than `bottom`.

Comment: For completeness sake, the actual equations I meant are `left + width + right = parentContentWidth` and `top + height + bottom = parentContentHeight`.

Comment: @mhelvens Reasons behind conventions are not explained in the spec. I think questions like *"Why do absolutely positioned replaced elements treat like so", "Why isn't margin applicable to table-cells", "Why is a percentage value on top/bottom margin/padding relative to the width of the containing block"*, ... are better asked on [WWW-style mailing list](http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/www-style/). There might be a technical reason. Just found a similar topic about behavior of `overflow` property [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9943503/1725764).